# AngularJS $http POST is transformed into GET

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS with Codeigniter back-end. I have used this combination for several projects now so I am familiar with techique to get $http.post to work with PHP backend but this time I am strugling with that. What ever I try I always get null in backends POST.

Investigating problem I found that for some reason my POST is transfered into GET. AngularJS code:

```
return $http({
    action: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + '/auth/register',
    data: {
        lat: coords.lat,
        lng: coords.lng
    }
}).then(function(response){

},function(msg){

});
```

However in dev tools I get this:

> Request URL:http://mydomain/auth/register Request
>
> Method:GET
>
> Status Code:200 OK
>
> Remote Address:[::1]:80 Referrer
>
> Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

This behavior repeat no matter what Changes I do in $http call - whether I change headers or format of data. I am not sure if this is the reason behind not being able to get POST data in backend but well I have tried techique that worked in other projects so I believe that there is some relevance.

Comment: it should be `method: 'POST'` not `action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `action: 'POST'`, change it to `method: 'POST'` as below.

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + '/auth/register',
    data: {
        lat: coords.lat,
        lng: coords.lng
    }
}).then(function(response){

},function(msg){

});
```

You can also use the shortcut method post as below:

```
var postParams = {
            lat: coords.lat,
            lng: coords.lng
        };
 $http.post(postParams)
    .then(function(response) {
        //First function handles success
    }, function(response) {
        //Second function handles error
    });
```